# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PK3' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure to insert data in a pattern,

```
DECLARE @I INT = 1
DECLARE @ID INT = 0
DECLARE @PackID VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @PackID = MAX(PackID) 
FROM tblPacks 
WHERE PackID LIKE 'PK%'

IF(@String = 'Packs')
BEGIN
    WHILE @I <= @Count
    BEGIN
        IF @PackID IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @I = @I + 1
            SET @ID = @ID + 1

            INSERT INTO tblPacks (T_ID, BatchNumber, PackID, Status, BlistersCount)
            VALUES (@T_ID, @BatchNumber,
                    'PK'+ CAST(@ID as VARCHAR(50)), 0,
                    (SELECT NumberOfBlistersInEachPack 
                     FROM tblPackDetails 
                     WHERE T_ID = @T_ID AND BatchNumber = @BatchNumber))
        END        
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
            SET @I = @I + 1
          error :-  SELECT @ID = (SELECT MAX(PackID) FROM tblPacks)
            SET @ID = @ID + 1

            INSERT INTO tblPacks (T_ID, BatchNumber, PackID, Status,  BlistersCount)  
             VALUES (@T_ID, @BatchNumber,
                     'PK'+ CAST(@ID as VARCHAR(50)), 0,
                     (SELECT NumberOfBlistersInEachPack 
                      FROM tblPackDetails 
                      WHERE T_ID = @T_ID AND BatchNumber = @BatchNumber))
            END
        END
    END
END
```

It is showing an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PK3' to data type int.

If packid is null then it Should be 'PK1' and if it has some data then it will take max value and then it should be incremented by'1'. Where should I modify my code to get rid of this error?

Comment: In your `table` tblPacks what is the `datatype` of `column` PackID ?

Comment: Varchar Data type @Abhishek

Answer (score 3):

Try to put the below statement in your insert query

```
 ('PK'+CAST(@ID as VARCHAR(50)))
```

Here first we need to convert integer type to varchar then concatenate it.

Comment: Getting Same Error

Comment: DId you declared @string as varchar or int? please include declare statement in your question. Also can you include tblPacks columns with data types in your question. Also include tblPackDetails columns T_ID, BatchNumber datatypes.

Comment: T_ID INT ,
BatchNumber VARCHAR(30) ,
Count INT,String VARCHAR(30) and PackID in tblPacks as VARCHAR(100)   @Srinath

Comment: what about tblPcakDetails table column datatypes?

Comment: The error is here :- check it out    SELECT @ID=(SELECT MAX(PackID) FROM tblPacks)  @Srinath

Comment: How your are telling ?. It wont throw error. Just it will return max of packid(whether it is int or varchar).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132153/discussion-between-srinath-and-sai-bharath).

Answer (score 0):

Try this once it may help you.
First convert the integer variable to string and then concatenate with string variable.
Add this chunk in your query and enjoy..

```
'PK'+ CAST(@ID as VARCHAR(50))
```

```
DECLARE @I INT=1
        DECLARE @ID INT=0
        DECLARE @PackID VARCHAR(50)


    SELECT @PackID=MAX(PackID) FROM tblPacks WHERE PackID LIKE 'PK%'

    IF(@String='Packs')
    BEGIN
    WHILE @I<=@Count
    BEGIN
    IF @PackID IS NULL
    BEGIN
    SET @I=@I+1
    SET @ID=@ID+1
    INSERT INTO tblPacks (T_ID,BatchNumber,PackID,Status,BlistersCount)
    VALUES (
        @T_ID,@BatchNumber,
     'PK'+ CAST(@ID as VARCHAR(50)) ,0,(SELECT NumberOfBlistersInEachPack FROM tblPackDetails WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber))

    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN 
    SET @I=@I+1
    SELECT @ID=(SELECT MAX(PackID) FROM tblPacks)
    SET @ID=@ID+1
    INSERT INTO tblPacks (T_ID,BatchNumber,PackID,Status,BlistersCount)
    VALUES (
        @T_ID,@BatchNumber,
      'PK'+ CAST(@ID as VARCHAR(50)) ,0,(SELECT NumberOfBlistersInEachPack FROM tblPackDetails WHERE T_ID=@T_ID AND BatchNumber=@BatchNumber))
    END
    END
    END
END
```

Comment: Getting Same Error

Answer (score 0):

You also can you some string function to convert the int to varchar,for example:

```
DECLARE @ID INT =100
SELECT 'PK'+LTRIM(@ID)
```

Comment: Getting Same Error

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the line# in which you are getting error. This is just a conversion error. Please specify the table definition as well. Refer the below query. I have changed the concatenation part. If the error still persists, please share the table definition and errored line#. Also what is the data type of `PackID` column in `tblPacks`? The `PackID` is non numeric and you are trying to assign that value to `@ID` which is declared as INT. This is the problem. I strongly suggest using some other value instead of taking the Maximum of a string. I have modified the query again to take maximum from the `SUBSTRING` of `PackID`

```
DECLARE @I INT = 1
DECLARE @ID INT = 0
DECLARE @MaxPackID VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @PackID VARCHAR(50)


SELECT @PackID = MAX(PackID) 
FROM tblPacks 
WHERE PackID LIKE 'PK%'

IF(@String = 'Packs')
BEGIN
    WHILE @I <= @Count
    BEGIN
        IF @PackID IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @I = @I + 1
            SET @ID = @ID + 1

            INSERT INTO tblPacks (T_ID, BatchNumber, PackID, Status, BlistersCount)
            VALUES (@T_ID, @BatchNumber,
                    'PK' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(50)), 0,
                    (SELECT NumberOfBlistersInEachPack 
                     FROM tblPackDetails 
                     WHERE T_ID = @T_ID AND BatchNumber = @BatchNumber))
        END        
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
            SET @I = @I + 1
            SELECT @MaxPackID = MAX(SUBSTRING(PackID,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',PackID),LEN(PackID))) FROM tblPacks
            SELECT @ID = @MaxPackID
            SET @ID = @ID + 1

            INSERT INTO tblPacks (T_ID, BatchNumber, PackID, Status,  BlistersCount)  
             VALUES (@T_ID, @BatchNumber,
                     'PK' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(50)), 0,
                     (SELECT NumberOfBlistersInEachPack 
                      FROM tblPackDetails 
                      WHERE T_ID = @T_ID AND BatchNumber = @BatchNumber))
            END
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: It is getting error here :-   SELECT @ID = (SELECT MAX(PackID) FROM tblPacks) And PackID is VARCHAR

Comment: Updated Please check once more

Comment: @saibharath: This will work when 'PK' is the only string which is appended before each ID values else we may need to rephrase the query.

Comment: After Pk10 it is getting PK10 again @Gopakumar N.Kurup

Comment: @saibharath As I said, the design is not proper. The MAX(PackID) will not work as you are expecting. The string MAX will be different here PK9 will be higher than PK10. So either choose another ID or if you are sure about the values then take the maximum based on the SUBSTRING function which I mentioned in the query. Please let me know whether you want me to rephrase the query.

Comment: Rather that modifying this again could you tell me How to increment a varchar like Pk1,pk2 etc..There should be no limit it may have Pk9999999 also so how can i do that? @Gopakumar N.Kurup

Comment: @saibharath If you want me to give a better idea, please share more information. Such as the design of the table. For example what is the T_ID and from where the value is getting populated, if it is an auto incremented value, then use that to generate the PackID. Or add a new column in tblPacks to hold the auto incremented values and then append them while generating the PackID. Also please vote if the answer is useful.

Comment: @saibharath Also did u check whether the latest query I shared is working?